# receiving error Unknown class PFImageView in Interface Builder file for parse

Tags: ios, storyboard, parse-platform

I attempted to setup pfimage view storyboards in the following manner:

I dragged a UIImageView and then changed its class identity to PFImageView.

Then I dragged it to create an outlet in my .h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *BuyPetImage;
```

Then on my on load for the class I access imageview with the same name as the property and set its file property.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    PFObject *petdataobj = [selectedPet objectForKey:@"petObject"];
    self.BuyPetNameLabel.text = [petdataobj objectForKey:@"Name"];
    self.BuyPetTypeLabel.text = [petdataobj objectForKey:@"Type"];

    self.BuyPetImage.file= [selectedPet objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    [self.BuyPetImage loadInBackground];
}
```

When the view loads I get the following error:

Unknown class PFImageView in Interface Builder file.
-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cdb52f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cdb52f0'

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: That sounds as if PFImageView.m hasn't been added to the target ("Target Membership" checkbox in the File inspector).

Comment: The pfimage is apart of a framework.  That framework is added to the target and all of its other features work.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that you get exactly this error message if you set a custom class for an object in Interface Builder and the class is not available at runtime because the .m file has not been added to the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get around this problem so I ended up just creating the PFImageView entirely in code. There's a couple examples of this in the [Anypic project](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic). I would like to figure out the cause of this problem and how to resolve it, but for now doing it in code allows me to get around it.

Answer (score 6):

"Unknown class PFImageView in Interface Builder file"

Adding the following to applicationDidLaunch in your AppDelegate forces the view class to load so it may be referenced correctly

//In AppDelegate / applicationDidLaunch add:

**[PFImageView class];**

//Pictures loads perfectly now!!:)

Comment: how do you do this in swift

Answer (score 0):

If I **alloc init** PFImageView in the .m file it works without adding [PFImageView class]; in appDelegate

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Where do you add this statement in the file